# Mysql Join date on one table

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have one table named `seismik`

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════╗
║      date     ║ type     ║ 
╠═══════════════╬══════════╣
║   2019-04-01  ║  rock    ║ 
║   2019-04-01  ║  water   ║
║   2019-04-01  ║  water   ║
║   2019-04-02  ║  rock    ║
║   2019-04-02  ║  rock    ║
║   2019-04-03  ║  water   ║
║   2019-04-03  ║  water   ║
║   2019-04-04  ║  rock    ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════╝
```

What I want to do is to count how much type rock in each date, but I want the date which don't have rock still exist and the value is null.

So I use this query

```
SELECT date,type, COUNT(`type`) AS `freq`
FROM seismik 
WHERE type = "rock"
GROUP BY date_time
```

And the result become

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║      date     ║ type     ║ freq    ║ 
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║   2019-04-01  ║  rock    ║    1    ║
║   2019-04-02  ║  rock    ║    2    ║
║   2019-04-04  ║  rock    ║    1    ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

What I expected is

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║      date     ║ type     ║ freq    ║ 
╠═══════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║   2019-04-01  ║  rock    ║    1    ║
║   2019-04-02  ║  rock    ║    2    ║
║   2019-04-03  ║  null    ║   null  ║ <- This
║   2019-04-04  ║  rock    ║    1    ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: *"SQL-92 and earlier does not permit queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are not named in the GROUP BY clause"* see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html), your query is invalid.also with functionally dependency which cant be used on this data.

Comment: Without a PRIMARY KEY, you don't really have a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `case when` and remove the `where` condition

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5cedbfcad288380e51951a55a4ca7072)**

```
 SELECT dateval,max(case when types='rock' then types end) types, COUNT(case when `types`='rock' then 1 end) AS `freq`
 FROM t1 
 GROUP BY dateval
```

OUTPUT:

```
dateval     types   freq
2019-04-01  rock    1
2019-04-02  rock    2
2019-04-03          0
2019-04-04  rock    1
```

Comment: +1 for the update, also i really need coffee, when i read your  update i was noticing i did the very hard way off using a cross join to generate the missing record totally mist the more easy method and forgotten that `MAX()` produces a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.Date,e.type,count(e.type)/4 
FROM seismik as s left join seismik as e
on e.type = s.type and e.type='rock'
GROUP BY date;
```

Result:-

> 2019-04-01    rock    1.0000
>
> 2019-04-02    rock    2.0000
>
> 2019-04-04    rock    1.0000
>
> 2019-04-03            0.0000

Answer (score -1):

In your query, you are selecting all entries, that have the type "rock". If you want also want to get those with type null, you will have to remove your where-clause.

Comment: invalid GROUP BY, type is not in the GROUP BY